# How can I remove text on the last line of a file?

Tags: bash

I am using a Bash shell script to construct a text file that contains a Javascript array. As far as I understand with Javascript, the last item in an array can't have a comma. In my Javascripts, that gives me errors.

I have a list of items that is generated with other code, and the result looks something like this:

```
text0161: "blah",
text0162: "blah blah",
text0163: "blah blah blah",
```

I need to take the very last line, `text0163: "blah blah blah",` and remove the trailing comma, so it becomes `text0163: "blah blah blah"`.

At this point in my processing, there is nothing after `text0163: "blah blah blah"`, so I can just look for the very last line in the file and remove the comma. However, the contents of the line might change, so it won't always be exactly `text0163: "blah blah blah",`. It might become just about anything else, like `text2020: "doobie doobie doo",`.

I know I can use sed to delete the comma, like this:

```
sed -i 's@,@@g' file.txt
```

But I don't know how to *only* do that on the last line.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can specify the address of your specific command/regular expression. The last line is represented by `$`, so in your case it would be:

```
sed -i '$ s/,$//' file.txt
```

Please note that i replaces your `@` with `/` as they are more commonly used in regular expressions.

This regular expression also removes only the comma at the end of the line, e.g. if there is a space after the comma or the comma is in the quoted text it will not be removed.

Answer (score 1):

In sed, you can match the last line with `$`, and there is a command `d` which deletes the current line:

```
sed -i '$d' file.txt
```